# iOS - Clear application data on application uninstallation

Tags: ios, swift

I need to clear the application data completely while the user is uninstalling an iOS application. These are some of the persistence storages i would target to delete. Please add incase if i miss anything

1. Keychain
2. NSDocumentsDirectory
3. NSUserDefaults
4. Core data
5. Sqllite
6. iCloud
7. Plist files
8. CSV
9. XML
10. Images & Assets

Does the OS itself takes care of deleting all the files above?

Comment: Did you research? What did you find for each? Where are some of the file formats you list stored???

Comment: Yes i have. It seems NSUserDefaults, documents directories, images and other application assets will be cleared automatically when the app is uninstalled. Not sure on Core data, Sqlite, iCloud, plist, CSV and xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Your app has neither the responsibility nor the ability to perform cleanup when it’s being uninstalled—once the user removes the app, your code ceases to run. On app uninstallation, iOS removes both the app bundle (containing any resources that shipped with the app) and the app container (containing any files that the app wrote within its sandbox while it was running). Some kinds of data, like keychain items that have a group identifier, can persist after the app is removed, but, again, you have no control over that at the point of uninstallation.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing back. Do we have any apple developer links to justify this.

Comment: I don’t know of anywhere in particular that it’s documented, but you can easily verify it experimentally. For the bundle itself: create a large (multi-MB) app and install / uninstall it while checking the amount of free space on the system in the Settings app. For app data / user defaults, make your app drop some files on the disk, uninstall it, and reinstall a different version that checks for the presence of those files / defaults.